Automatically filtered a specific element in a list and input them in a separate lists
I am working on a large list of data. The list should look like this
List=[1,2,3,0,0,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,0,7,8,9]

It consists of chain of positive number, and is discreted by 0 values. I want to take to chain of positive numbers and put them in separate lists in stead of only one list of positive numbers. The output should be like this
List1=[1,2,3]
List2=[4,5,6]
List3=[7,8,9]

So the first set of positive numbers is filter and the loop is break when 0 is encountered. Then a new list is created with the filtered elements. After that enter a new loop and do that process one more time until the last element of the original list.
Also the number of list is unknown.
I try to generate a set of lists of positive values. It seems like for loop and while loop is insufficient. Really need help on this one, really appreciate your help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It can be done quite easily by iterating the list and tracking a flag to know if we are currently filling a list of positive numbers, or if we are going through zeros. When we get a positive number and this flag is true, we create a new list of positive numbers and set this flag to false. If the flag is false, then we simply append this number to the current list of positive numbers. When we encounter a zero, we reset this flag to true, so the next time we hit a positive number, we create a new list for it:
def split_list(lst):
    results = []
    start_new_list = True
    for x in lst:
        if x > 0:
            if start_new_list:
                results.append([])
                start_new_list = False
            results[-1].append(x)
        else:
            start_new_list = True
    return results


List = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9]
print(split_list(List))

There is another way to do it in one line using itertools.groupby and list comprehension. The itertools.groupby(it, key_func) function accepts an iterable (our input list) and a key_func function to group the elements of the iterable by. It will return an iterator of the groups of our iterable. Each group is a tuple of the form (key, g) where key is the value the key_func function returned for this group and g is the group of elements matching this key. In our example, we can group the list by positive numbers:
result = groupby(List, key=lambda x: x > 0)

For the List in your example this would return
[
    (True, [1, 2, 3]),  # First group of positive numbers
    (False, [0, 0, 0, 0]),  # Second group of zeros
    (True, [4, 5, 6]),  # 3rd group of positive numbers
    (False, [0, 0, 0, 0]),  # 4th group of zeros
    (True, [7, 8, 9]),  # Last group of zeros
]

Note that the groups returned by groupby aren't actually lists, but rather iterators, so we need to convert them into lists. We also need to discard the groups of zeros we don't want. Both of these goals can be accomplished with a list comprehension:
from itertools import groupby

List = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9]
res = [list(g) for is_positive, g in groupby(List, key=lambda x: x > 0) if is_positive]
print(res)


The groupby solution is neat :)

It works. Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help!

You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

I'm not 100% sure about what you want to achieve, but judging by your desired output maybe something like this?
def split_list(lst):
    output = []
    temp = []
    for i in lst:
        if i != 0:
            temp.append(i)
        elif temp:
            output.append(temp)
            temp = []
    if temp:
        output.append(temp)
    return output


It works. Really appreciate your answer!

Three solutions using an explicit iterator:
def split_list1(lst):
    results = []
    it = iter(lst)
    for x in it:
        if x:
            pos = [x]
            results.append(pos)
            for x in it:
                if not x:
                    break
                pos.append(x)
    return results

def split_list2(lst):
    results = []
    it = iter(lst)
    for x in it:
        if x:
            results.append([x, *iter(it.__next__, 0)])
    return results

def split_list3(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    nx = it.__next__
    return [
        [x, *iter(nx, 0)]
        for x in it
        if x
    ]

List = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9]
for f in split_list1, split_list2, split_list3:
    print(f(List))

Attempt This Online!
